# Does there exist a c# framework/plugin or pattern to allow dynamic setting of expected values in tests?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I have numerous unit tests within my solution. I'm using NUnit and have a lot of Asserts all over the place e.g. Assert.AreEqual(5, someVar).

This sort of pattern of testing expected numbers versus actual numbers is repeated a lot.

The project I'm working on involves a lot of tweaking of the models that produce these numbers. My current process is, I'll tweak the model based on requirements and this will throw off all my Unit Tests as expected. What then begins is the manual process of updating all the expected values in my Assert to match the new actual values so that my Unit Tests stop breaking until another tweak to the model is required.

My question is, does there exist a plugin or a pattern such that all the expected numbers within the Asserts can be updated automatically with the actual values when I require them to?

Comment: Take a look at using [TestCaseData](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData) to combine your input and expected output in one place.

Comment: Looks interesting - thank you Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a universally applied starting value that you can change without recalculating your asserts.

For example, say you are doing ICalculator with .AddOne() and .TimesTwo() methods

You can set a _startingNumber = 1
Tests for AddOne() Assert(_startingNumber + 1, result)
Tests for TimesTwo() Assert(_startingNumber * 2, result)

When you change _startingNumber your Asserts stay correct.
If you are asserting logic and not values you could try a lookup table

```
    _lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    _lookup.Add("SaveStatus", "SaveValue");
    _lookup.Add("DeletedStatus", "DeletedValue");
```

Then your assert looks like Assert(_lookup["SaveStatus"], result)

So if today you are expecting "SaveValue" but tomorrow you are expecting "SaveValueNew" you can change it in the lookup but all the asserts expecting a save status will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are approaching this the right way round.

Your unit tests show that your current model is working as expected.

If you are going to change your model, you should first change your unit test assertions so that they match how you would like your model to behave.

Then you change your model and run the unit tests to see if everything has worked.

To change the model first and then automatically change the assertion values in your tests so that they match what the changed model is producing renders the unit tests effectively useless. They cannot be telling you if there is any problem with the way you implemented the model changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - agreed with everything you've said and that is how I would normally work. With the model I'm working with, it's impossible to know what the value will be until it has run due to the complex calculations. 

As for rendering the unit tests useless, that is not the case, as I only want the numbers to change on command.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [Mocking](http://www.developerhandbook.com/unit-testing/writing-unit-tests-with-nunit-and-moq/)

You can install it with NuGet Packages in VS.

Comment: It's not mocking as I cannot mock the output. I need to calculate the output and then change it.